# How can I add a class to a popover with vue boostrap?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have:

```
    <li class="nav-item">
      <b-popover
        target="search-button"
        placement="topleft"
        title="Search"
        triggers="click"
        content="Placement"
        container="nav-container"
      >
        <template slot="title">Interactive Content</template>
        <template slot="content">Interactive Content</template>
      </b-popover>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" title="Popover Title" id="search-button">
        <i class="material-icons md-48">search</i>
      </a>
    </li>
```

I want to add a class to the `popover`, but ideally have it scoped to this component. When I try to do:

```
<style scoped>
.nav {
  background: white;
  border-top: 0.1px solid silver;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.popover {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
</style>
```

It seems to have no impact on the actual popover.

Comment: Did you try to give class with `queryselector`? You can add it in `mounted`.

Comment: I can - it seems a bit hacky though, no?

Comment: Yeah. But if you can't find better way try with that. :D

Comment: It works, but there's a noticeable lag as the popover becomes wider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 2.0.0-rc.26 (which is to be released soon) adds support for tooltip/popover variants as well as applying custom classes to the tooltip/popover root element.

You can see a preview at https://bootstrap-vue.netlify.com/ (and will appear at https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/ once released)

Comment: Version 2.0.0-rc.26 has been released.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to give class to `<b-popover>`, you can read [here](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/2075).

But as I mentioned in comment you can use `querySelector` and give class or styling.

Cheers.